# Open encrypted trigger of table in database (MS SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Microsoft SQL Server Question for Trigger in database-tables.
Is there a possibility to view Code behind a encrypted trigger of a database table?
I only see a key inside the Icon and rightclick "Change" is Grey.

Need some help please

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to view Code behind a encrypted trigger of a database table?

Yes, but since it's most likely against the TOS, I'll leave it as that and tell you if you really really want to get at the code to search the internet.

I hate to leave the answer that short, but that's the whole point of encrypting it. If this is your code and you did this, note that you'll want to save the original text in a managed repository or other source code system. If it's not yours, you may be violating a TOS, EULA, or other laws depending on the situation and opening yourself up to liabilities.